# Sorting a hasheq list in Racket

Tags: hashmap, hashtable, racket

I am creating a function 'sort-mail' in Racket, that takes in a list of hash-eq s and sorts them based on their Data key. The input is defined this way:

```
 (define test-dates
    '("Sun, 10 Sep 2017 09:48:44 +0200"
      "Wed, 13 Sep 2017 17:51:05 +0000"
      "Sun, 10 Sep 2017 13:16:19 +0200"
      "Tue, 17 Nov 2009 18:21:38 -0500"
      "Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:40:47 -0700"
      "Thu, 14 Sep 2017 12:03:35 -0700"
      "Wed, 18 Nov 2009 02:22:12 -0800"
      "Sat, 09 Sep 2017 13:40:18 -0700"
      "Tue, 26 Oct 2010 15:11:06 +0200"
      "Tue, 17 Nov 2009 18:04:31 -0800"
      "Mon, 17 Oct 2011 04:15:12 +0000"
      "Sun, 16 Oct 2011 23:12:02 -0500"
      "Mon, 11 Sep 2017 14:41:12 +0100"))

 (define test-hashes (map (lambda (x) (hasheq 'Date x)) test-dates))
```

I have tried following the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595165/sorting-a-hash-table-in-racket?rq=1) question, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for. So far, I am trying to sort them using the following:

```
 (define (sort-mail test-hashes)
    (sort test-hashes #:key car <))
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error:
     car:contract violation
     expected: pair?
     given: 'hasheq((Data . "Wed, 13 Sept 2017 17:51:05 +0000"

I'm pretty confused as to what my sort statement should look like, so any guidance would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

First, the reason for the error message is that `sort` calls [`car`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=rfc2822#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._car%29%29) (the `#:key` function) on each element of the `test-hashes` list, and each of those elements is a hash-table, not a list. `car` expects a list, hence the error.

Your `#:key` function needs to extract the date from the hash table. `hash-ref` does that. So here's a first attempt at `sort-mail`:

```
(define (sort-mail hash-tables)
  (define (date-of ht) (hash-ref ht 'Date))
  (sort hash-tables #:key date-of string<?))
```

This brings us to the second problem, which is the function for comparing dates. Notice that the comparison function above is `string<?` rather than `<`. That's because the value associated the `Date` key in each hash table is a string. Calling `string<?` avoids a run-time type error, but the dates get sorted in the wrong order:

```
> (sort-mail test-hashes)
'(#hasheq((Date . "Mon, 11 Sep 2017 14:41:12 +0100"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Mon, 17 Oct 2011 04:15:12 +0000"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Sat, 09 Sep 2017 13:40:18 -0700"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Sun, 10 Sep 2017 09:48:44 +0200"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Sun, 10 Sep 2017 13:16:19 +0200"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Sun, 16 Oct 2011 23:12:02 -0500"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Thu, 14 Sep 2017 12:03:35 -0700"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Tue, 17 Nov 2009 18:04:31 -0800"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Tue, 17 Nov 2009 18:21:38 -0500"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Tue, 26 Oct 2010 15:11:06 +0200"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:40:47 -0700"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Wed, 13 Sep 2017 17:51:05 +0000"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Wed, 18 Nov 2009 02:22:12 -0800")))
```

As you can see, the dates are sorted alphabetically, not by date. Really, then, you need a `#:key` function that returns the date represented in a way that can easily be compared with other dates.

Your date strings are stored in a format called [RFC-2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.html#section-3.3). I did a quick search of the Racket documentation and didn't find a standard library function to parse RFC-2822 date strings. Some googling turned up [this blog post](https://tero.hasu.is/blog/2013-01-06-racket-time-conversion.html) by Tero Hasu, which includes a function to convert RFC-2822 date strings into Unix times. A "Unix time" is a time represented as the number of seconds since January 1, 1970. That's a number, so you can compare it with `<`.

Here's the code pasted from Tero Hasu's blog:

```
(require (prefix-in s. srfi/19))

(define (rfc2822->unix-time s) ;; string -> integer
  (let ((d (s.string->date s "~a, ~d ~b ~Y ~H:~M:~S ~z")))
    (s.time-second (s.date->time-utc d))))
```

And finally, here's the corrected `sort-mail`:

```
(define (sort-mail hash-tables)
  (define (ht->unix-time ht) (rfc2822->unix-time (hash-ref ht 'Date)))
  (sort hash-tables #:key ht->unix-time <))

> (sort-mail test-hashes)
'(#hasheq((Date . "Tue, 17 Nov 2009 18:21:38 -0500"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Tue, 17 Nov 2009 18:04:31 -0800"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Wed, 18 Nov 2009 02:22:12 -0800"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Tue, 26 Oct 2010 15:11:06 +0200"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Sun, 16 Oct 2011 23:12:02 -0500"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Mon, 17 Oct 2011 04:15:12 +0000"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Sat, 09 Sep 2017 13:40:18 -0700"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Sun, 10 Sep 2017 09:48:44 +0200"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Sun, 10 Sep 2017 13:16:19 +0200"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Mon, 11 Sep 2017 14:41:12 +0100"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:40:47 -0700"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Wed, 13 Sep 2017 17:51:05 +0000"))
  #hasheq((Date . "Thu, 14 Sep 2017 12:03:35 -0700")))
```